# Way to subscribe to an angular FormGroup getting focused in and out

Tags: angular, onfocus, formgroups

I would like to know if any input inside an angular `FormGroup` did get focused in or out and set it into a variable like `focused: boolean`

I could add `(focus)` to every inputs, but it seems a bit dirty.

Is it somehow doable ?

#### Objective

I'm trying to hide some information when the user is typing on the smartphone, because the keyboard do take a lot of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use single subscribtion on the parent, but instead of focus event you can subscribe to [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event) event. and because it bubbles, the parent element will catch this event on all of its children

Comment: Yes it what I initially though. But when I switch between input, then the focus get triggered again.  For not I did add a timeout of `300` to check if the user did click again on an input and only trigger the animation if the variable is still the same (focus in for example) but this seems to be dirty

Comment: are you using css animations for your case?

Comment: Yes, and also `@angular/animations` for hiding some elements.

Comment: if the animation if 100% css one you could try to make use of `:focus-within` selector to turn if on or off.